# format String using sed

Tags: sed, text-formatting

How to format the following input strings to output strings using sed?

The center string should start at 20th character and end string should start at 40th character.

input:

```
begining center end     
beg12  cen12  end12
beg13 cen  end
```

output:

```
begining     center      end     
beg12        cen12       end12
beg13        cen         end
```

Comment: how about using `column -t file`?

Answer (score 2):

`awk` may be used to format this data with its `printf()` function.

```
$ awk '{ printf("%-20s%-20s%s\n", $1, $2, $3) }' data.in
begining            center              end
beg12               cen12               end12
beg13               cen                 end
```

This assumes that the data in the file is whitespace-separated.

To give it the column width as a parameter:

```
$ cols=40
$ awk -v c="$cols" 'BEGIN { fmt=sprintf("%%-%ds%%-%ds%%s\n", c, c) } { printf(fmt, $1, $2, $3) }' data.in
begining                                center                                  end
beg12                                   cen12                                   end12
beg13                                   cen                                     end
```

Comment: this is cleaner than my answer. and one of the only times I've ever seen awk as a superior solution to more basic text processing tools like `sed`

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those occasions where I wouldn't use `sed`, I would use `printf`, particularly the
`%-Ns` format which will pad the string with blanks until the "field" occupies a minimum of `N` characters

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read first second third
do
    printf "%-20s%-20s%s\n" "$first" "$second" "$third"
done <<- 'EOF' 
    begining center end     
    beg12  cen12  end12
    beg13 cen  end
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk '{printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s\n",$1,$2,$3)}' file
```

The output:

```
begining            center              end                 
beg12               cen12               end12               
beg13               cen                 end
```

Answer (score 1):

You already got answers with other tools, `column` being the most obvious. I agree that `sed` is not the tool of choice for this, but if you already use `sed` to get the table, it's nasty to pipe that output to another tool just for formatting. In this case use something like this at the end of your script:

```
sed 's/  */    /g;s/ /     /g;s/\(.\{20\}\) */\1/g'
```

This replaces all groups of spaces by four spaces, then each space by five spaces, so we have padded 20 spaces. The third `s` command keeps the first 20 chars of each column and removes remaining spaces.

Comment: if you use sed in extended regex mode you could do: `sed -r 's/  */    /g;s/ /     /g;s/(.{20}) */\1/g'` its a bit cleaner

Comment: Agreed, but I think that `-E` is more portable for ERE usage than `-r` (some versions support both, some only `-E`). Btw, the multiple spaces got lost in your comment, maybe due to the comment formatting.

Comment: interesting, my preference is to use `-E` because you can just think if it as "extended" and thats consistent with `grep`  as well, but I used `-r` because my `sed` (gnu `sed`) doesn't mentioned `-E` anywhere, so I thought `-E` was deprecated as not being portable

Comment: According to [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) `-r`/`-E` *historically  was a GNU extension, but the `-E` extension has since been added to the POSIX standard (http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528), so use `-E` for portability. GNU `sed` has accepted `-E` as an undocumented option for years, and *BSD `sed`s have accepted `-E` for years as well, but scripts that use `-E` might not port to other older systems.* So they suggest using `-E` except for old GNU systems. No idea why they don't include it in the man page and say `-r` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

```
< yourfile tr -s '\t ' '\t\t' | expand -t 19,39
```

---

### Results

```
         1         2         3         4         5
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
begining           center              end
beg12              cen12               end12
beg13              cen                 end
```

---

### Working

- First we squeeze out all residual spaces and/or TABs to TABs only.
- Then we apply the `expand` command on the resultant by using the `-t` option and listing out the tab positions.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/  */    /g;s/ /     /g;s/\(.\{20\}\) */\1/g'
```

-> This gives space in every word.

beginning and end has only one word. center has multiple words.

```
beginning          center cntr cnt center              end
beg12              cen12  cnt cntr                     end12
beg13              cen center                          end
```

Comment: How is this different from the answer given by @Philippos ?

Comment: sed 's/  */    /g;s/ /     /g;s/\(.\{20\}\) */\1/g'  Adds more spaces in every center words. It should give only one space between center words.

Comment: Any sed answer for String spaces ?